# Opening Keyboard Pushes Up My Whole View React-Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a simple weather application I built to help teach myself React-Native. I am mostly done with the application but I cannot solve the problem of the keyboard pushing up all the elements in the view, making the layout very ugly while typing into the text field. I want the keyboard to open and just lay *over* the components on the bottom of the screen instead of pushing them upwards.

I have read that changing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` should fix my issue through other questions on SO. I have tried changing to both `adjustPan` and `adjustNothing` but I do not see any changes in my applications behavior. The `KeyboardAvoidingView` component doesn't help me here since I need my View component to do the opposite.

What am I missing here?

Comment: how we can help you without code source ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result I used a work around by Setting

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` on the `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` located at `\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: That solves the issue, but also renders every <KeyboardAvoidingView> useless.

Comment: What about iOS? I am facing this issue in iOS as well.

Comment: @dhruvsoni i'm facing the same issue in iOS, too. Have you had solution?

Comment: @my-will I had to make some design changes and we used this package called `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` to allow users to scroll over the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You have to set translucent to false in app.json file.

```
"androidStatusBar": {
      "hidden": false,
      "translucent": false,
      "iosBarStyle": "light-content",
      "barStyle": "light-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#colorCode"
    }
```

Or if you want a translucent status bar as well, use  in App.js

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#colorCode',
              }}
            >
              <StatusBar backgroundColor="#colorCode" barStyle="light-content" />
            </View>
            <OtherComponent..... />
          </View>
    );
  }
}
```